# google map markers performance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

on my web site http://offersmapper.com/
i have a map that has to show from 2000 to 5000 markers. is really slow.
i tried with markercluster as suggested but nothing... most probably i'm doing something wrong... any one that can help me?:

```
function initialize() {  
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: <? echo $zoom; ?>,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $lat ?>, <? echo $lng ?>),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);  

var markers_1 = [];

<?
while($deal=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$t="
var contentString".$deal['id']."='".$info."';

var InfoWin".$deal['id']."= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString".$deal['id'].",
      maxWidth: 300
    });

var marker".$deal['id']." = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(".$deal['lat'].", ".$deal['lng']."),
  icon: ".$icon."
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker".$deal['id'].", 'click', function() {
    InfoWin".$deal['id'].".open(map,marker".$deal['id'].");
  });

markers_1.push(marker".$deal['id'].");"; 

echo $t;
}
?>
var markerCluster_1 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers_1, {maxZoom: 7, gridSize: 25, styles: styles[0]} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reduce your html code:
You should pass data to javascript as a json object. Than javascript should iterate over all elements and create markers , etc.. mutch sorter html code, and faster load.

I assume you use jQuery for javascript coding:

```
      ... //your code before the while loop
      <?
      $deals = array();
      while($deal=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
           $deals[$deal[$id]] = $deal;
      }?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var deals = <?=json_encode($deals)?>;             
         var infoWindow = [];
         var marker =[];
         $.each(deals,function(k,v){ 
              var i = k; 
              infoWindow[i] = new  google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
                 content: v.info, 
                 maxWidth: 300 }); 
              markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(v.lat, v.lng), icon: v.icon 
              });
              google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i] , 'click', function(){
                  infoWindow[i].open(map,markers[i]);
              });
         });
         var markerCluster_1 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {maxZoom: 7, gridSize: 25, styles: styles[0]} );
      </script>
```

And if it is not enough,  you can load the data via ajax.

Comment: thanks a lot... but your code was retourning some error... i tried to change it in this way:

Comment: `var deals = <?= json_encode($deals)?>;
var markers_1 = [];
$.each(deals,function(k,v){
var i = k;
              
              var infoWindow+v.id = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: v.info,
                    maxWidth: 300
              });
              var marker+v.id = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(v.lat, v.lng),
                 icon: v.icon
              });
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker+v.id , 'click', function() {dinfoWindow+v.id.open(map,marker+v.id);});markers_1.push(marker+v.id);});`

Comment: nope........ there still an error... sorry... i couln't fix it.... SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Interrompi per questo errore]  

var infoWin[k] = new  google.maps.InfoWindow({

Comment: modified.. var is not need infoWindow[i], and markers[i] because, these values are declared previously.